# MAUI - What is the syntax for binding the Title itself to the Model?

Tags: bind, maui, title

On some contentPage I need the Title to be dynamic and also to be localized, so it should bind to, say, `MyModel.CountOfObjects` and have the form "6 objects in your inventory", where the string "objects in your inventory" should be localized. So then, what's the syntax? I have tried things like:

```
Title="{Binding MyModel.CountOfObjects, StringFormat='{0} {x:Static res:AppRes.CountOfObjects}'}"
```

where, of course, `AppRes.CountOfObjects` is "6 objects in your inventory" for the English language.

My title does not show properly :-(

I cannot set the title in `OnAppearing()` because the count of objects changes because of actions in this current screen.

Thank you.

Comment: my first thought would be to use an IValueConverter, or just build the string dynamically in your VM

Comment: Can you show more of your code, especially the code behind, the root node of the XAML with the namespaces and other attributes as well as the code of `MyModel`?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't figure it out yet / somone comes by: putting it like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="maui7App.Pages.TabbedWeekDashboard">
    <ContentPage.Title>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
            <Binding Path="Selected.Number" StringFormat="Selected Week: {0:D2}"/>
            <Binding Path="Selected.Year" StringFormat=" ({0})"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ContentPage.Title>
</ContentPage>
```

You need to have only one value for each binding. With the MultiBinding/Stringformat, you can combine them back together.
Here's my  guess for your code(not 100% sure if the second binding is correct, but you get the idea):

```
<ContentPage.Title>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
        <Binding Path="MyModel.CountOfObjects"/>
        <Binding Path="{x:Static res:AppRes.CountOfObjects}"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</ContentPage.Title>
```